# How to solve this error 'ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'none''

Tags: html, url, iframe

I am getting this error when try to load URL in I-fram.
Please help me with this.

Error:  **'ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'none'**

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Take the document you are trying to load in the frame.

Find the Content Security Policy for it, which could be in HTTP headers or `<meta>` tags.

Change the rules so that it allows the URL pointing to the document with your `<iframe>` element in it as an ancestor.

Comment: Thank you sir, but what content need to set in "Content Security Policy"

Comment: Depends on what, specifically, you want to allow. You could just remove the restriction you quoted entirely.

Comment: Can you check my site sir, when you hover on product and click on "eye" icon, ifram can not load data as you can see in console.
site: https://sample-store-1331.myshopify.com/collections/all

Comment: How can i set frame-ancestors '*' in request sir?

Comment: You can't. You have to set it in the response.

Comment: Then how can i solve sir, is there any way? i have shopify store

Comment: You have to set it in the response

Comment: @JasoliyaBrijesh did you resolve the issue, im facing the same issue but I don't know where do I have to set this in shopify to receive this in response.